# PL-SQL Block with substitution variables

Tags: sql, variables, sqlplus, substitution

I have to write PL/SQL Block that print salary of the people who have same job_title. Job_title must be entered in substitution variable. I struggle to print with 'dbms_output.put_line'. Also sql says that join is not right.

```
 DECLARE
  v_jobt VARCHAR2(50);
  v_sal Number ;
BEGIN
  SELECT j.job_title,e.salary INTO v_jobt, v_sal 
  FROM jobs j
  JOIN  EMPLOYEES e
  ON JOBS.JOB_ID=EMPLOYEES.salary
  WHERE  j.job_title = '&job_title';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Job Title is : ' ||v_jobt);
END;
```

Comment: FYI:  In SQL `WHERE` is **after** `JOIN`.

Comment: Even then I have errors.

Answer (score 1):

1, Put 'where clause' after 'join'

2, Use the Alias names in the 'on' condition

3, Add one single quote before ...is:'

**If you get the error message, please tell us what message you got.**

Try this:

```
DECLARE
 v_lname VARCHAR2(50);
 v_sal Number;
BEGIN
  SELECT j.job_title,e.salary INTO v_lname, v_sal 
  FROM jobs j 
  JOIN  EMPLOYEES e
  ON j.JOB_ID = e.JOB_ID
  WHERE  j.job_title = '&job_title';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('...is : ' ||v_lname);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know how I can add Average salary. "e.avg(salary)" is not right syntax.

Comment: Put alias on the field and not function. See if you need GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @YavorPetranov It should be avg(e.salary). You also need to add 'group by j.job_title' after where clause if you want to get the average salary for each job title.